# %!B(MISSING) different output between fmt.Printf and log.Println

Tags: go

I have some bytes returned from `json.Marshal`. If log them to stdout like this:

```
log.Println(string(b))
```

They are output like this:

```
{"encoded":"%2B"}
```

If I write them to disk with

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, string(b))
```

And then cat the file they have been written like this:

```
{"encoded":"%!B(MISSING)"}
```

As far as I can tell the output of `string(b)` really is the first, and my expected, output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fprintf](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) takes a format definition as the first argument. The `"%2B"` is interpreted as a formatting directive and you are missing the following argument.

Maybe you wanted to use [Fprint](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprint)?

Comment: In this page (http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) they show the following code snippet: `fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])`. Which is why I was using it. But yes, thank you. Adding a `"%s"` as the second argument or using Fprint fixes the problem.